# Как запустить команду npm при любом изменении любого файла в папке src?

Tags: npm

Всем привет! Подскажите, как можно запускать `npm run start` при любом сохранении любого файла в папке `src`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

возможно вы ищите [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon), который делает рестарт сервера автоматически, при изменении файлов в директории

Comment: спасибо за ответ! nodemon перезагружает сервер, это больше бэк. мне же нужно решение для фронта без поднятия сервера.

Comment: @CAHO nodemon может выполнить любую команду. Чаще всего это действительно перезагрузка сервера, но вовсе не обязательно.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, да, вы правы. Спасибо!

Comment: круто! пошёл вникать! спасибо за ответ :)